# Crypto++ is not decrypting an encrypted file

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I got the requirement to decrypt the input file using AES algorithm in CBC mode with given key. I tried to encrypt a sample file using AES algorithm in CBC mode using online tool [AES – Symmetric Ciphers Online](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/). Key used is "208512335119421110996C7761792045" .

I was able to encrypt the file and decrypt back the encrypted file to original content using this tool. I tried to do the same using cryptopp library with below code but it is not giving original file content.

Please point me what wrong I did here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
using CryptoPP::Exception;

#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter;

#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
using CryptoPP::AES;

#include "cryptopp/ccm.h"
using CryptoPP::CBC_Mode;



using namespace std;
std::string getFstr(std::string fname)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(fname.c_str());
    std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                       (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    return content;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
try
{
    std::string key_string = "208512335119421110996C7761792045";
    std::string enctext;        
     byte no[] = {0x2,0x0,0x8,0x5,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x3,0x5,0x1,0x1,0x9,0x4,0x2,0x1,0x1,0x1,0x0,0x9,0x9,0x6,0xC,0x7,0x7,0x6,0x1,0x7,0x9,0x2,0x0,0x4,0x5};

    byte noiv[32];
    std::string out;
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(no, 32);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, noiv );

    std::string fileName("in.txt");
    enctext = getFstr(fileName);
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(no, 32);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, noiv );
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( out ),CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING);
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( enctext.c_str() ), enctext.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    ofstream o("out.txt", ios::out|ios::binary);
    if ( o.good() )
    {
        o.write(out.c_str(),out.size());
        o.close();
    }
   return 0;
}
catch ( CryptoPP::Exception& e)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You should probably abandon `byte no[] = {...};` because it does not do what you think. You should probably run `std::string key_string` through a `HexDecoder`. Your key is probably 16, not 32. You should probably use `PKCS #5` padding. The website you linked uses ECB mode by default.

Comment: U are right jww I was wrong in interpreting key as combination of 2 digit is string representation of each byte value in hexadecimal for key. So key length is 16 and not 32.